# RGB numbers for pastel colordata

Tags: color

How can I get the rgb numbers for colors that show up in the colordata "pastel" so I can use them inside a regionplot? I am combining several regionplots and I would like each of the regionlots to be one color from the "Pastel" color scheme.

This thread [Sunset Colors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30508/blend-code-for-sunset-colors) tells me how to get some of the colors but it would be helpful to be able to get the codes for all possible blends on a continuum.

```
datt = DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`getColorSchemeData["Pastel"][[5]]

{RGBColor[0.761959, 0.470832, 0.940597], 
 RGBColor[0.809695, 0.585618, 0.953269], 
 RGBColor[0.866514, 0.647659, 0.771795], 
 RGBColor[0.909422, 0.699383, 0.647465], 
 RGBColor[0.937061, 0.764486, 0.598975], 
 RGBColor[0.954654, 0.842244, 0.587209], 
 RGBColor[0.962197, 0.913524, 0.594117], 
 RGBColor[0.948179, 0.953299, 0.634088], 
 RGBColor[0.891128, 0.944422, 0.72627], 
 RGBColor[0.771259, 0.887462, 0.856246], 
 RGBColor[0.594516, 0.801371, 0.955499], 
 RGBColor[0.431296, 0.709773, 0.927077]}


Table[RegionPlot[
  x > 0, {x, series[5][[22, 2]]/10000, 
   series[5][[22, 2]]/10000 + series[14][[22, 2]]/10000}, {y, 0, -1}, 
  PlotStyle -> k, AspectRatio -> Automatic], {k, datt}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Pastel` is a continuous function - which values do you want colors for?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30508/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and others. My question is answered exactly in the "Sunset Colors" link but fwiw I found Belisarius' and PlatoManiac's answers more helpful than Simon Woods' answer to the "Sunset Colors" question.

Comment: @Amatya you can re-`Blend` the colors you get from the dump.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the RGB of of your chosen color by clicking on the `"Pastel"` panel.

```
ColorData[ "Pastel", "Panel"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use it as `Colordata["Pastel"][x]`:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{ColorData["Pastel"], "Argument = " <> ToString[x], 
        Graphics[{FaceForm[ColorData["Pastel"][x]], Rectangle[]}]}], 
 {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, if you like that color, just use it like this:

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
           PlotStyle -> ColorData["Pastel"][0.418]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks Belisarius, that's very convenient form an implementation point of view. I will probably use your method in the end.