# Coloring an image with two Color schemes based on a Range

Tags: image-processing, color

I would like to color an image generated from some data, using two color schemes based on two ranges of the data. This is my attempt:

```
Image[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], 
      ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{ColorData["AlpineColors"][#],  0 < # < .5}, 
                                   {ColorData["SouthwestColors"][#], .5 < # < 1}}] &)]]
```

Comment: `ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{ColorData["LightTerrain"][#], 0 < # < .5}, {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#], .5 < # < 1}}] &),
  Frame -> None]`

Comment: Please see [(76610)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76610/121) as it has bearing on this question.

Answer (score 12):

Here is something 10 x faster.

I made the same assumption as george2079 so for each subinterval whole color scheme is used not just exact part like in Simon's answer. Maybe useful, maybe not.

#### Usage

```
colorF ~ createColorFunction ~ {"TemperatureMap", "AvocadoColors"};

pic = Image@ConstantArray[Range[0, 1, .001], 100]
Colorize[pic, ColorFunction -> colorF]
```

[image]
[image]

It is quite general, you can use arbitrary set of schemes:

```
colorF ~ createColorFunction ~  {"AlpineColors", "AvocadoColors", 
                                 "TemperatureMap", "SouthwestColors"};
Colorize[pic, ColorFunction -> colorF]
```

[image]

```
colorF ~ createColorFunction ~ RandomSample[ColorData["Gradients"], 10];
Colorize[pic, ColorFunction -> colorF]
```

[image]

```
colorF ~ createColorFunction ~ RandomSample[ColorData["Gradients"], 2];

Colorize[#, ColorFunction -> colorF, ColorFunctionScaling -> False] &@
 ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"]
```

[image]

The problem is condition which has to be checked for each pixel. We can take a walk around,

#### Definition

```
SetAttributes[createColorFunction, HoldFirst];
createColorFunction[functionname_, schemes_List] := Module[{
   colorss, setsNum, setsLength
   },
  Blend[{Red},1]; (*initialize `Color` stuff*)
  colorss = DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`getColorSchemeData[#][[5]] & /@ schemes;
  setsNum = Length@colorss;
  setsLength = Length /@ colorss;

  functionname = With[{colorSets = Transpose[{
        Accumulate[
         Join @@ Table[
           PadRight[{0}, setsLength[[i]], 
            1./((setsLength[[i]] - 1) setsNum)], {i, setsNum}]],
        Join @@ colorss}]
     },
    Blend[colorSets, #] &
    ]
  ]
```

#### Explanation

The ugly code in `Accumulate` takes lists of colors and creates:

```
{{c11, c12, c13}, {c21, c22, c23, c24, c25}}
------------->
{
 {0, 0.25, 0.5,    0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1.},
 {c11, c12, c13, c21, c22, c23, c24, c25}
} //Transpose
```

Which can be used to create `Blend` arguments. Colors sets are given by [Blend code for built-in ColorData schemes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30508/5478)

Comment: I feel inclined to produce my own version of this method.  Would you prefer that I edit your question to include it, or post my own answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard feel free to post your own if you want. I went with George's interpretation, you can with Simon's.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Colorize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Colorize.html) for this

```
Colorize[RandomImage[1, {10, 10}], ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[
 {{ColorData["AlpineColors"][#], 0 < # < .5},
  {ColorData["SouthwestColors"][#], .5 < # < 1}}] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get this, your code for `RandomImage[1, {100, 100}]` takes around `10s` but for `Image@ConstantArray[Range[0, 1, .01], 100]` only `0.5s`. It is not related to the type of data because `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Red}, #] &)` is fast for both. I tried your code with the first setup, that is why I commited to manual approach, which seems to be an overkill probably. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: @Kuba, weird. I have no idea why that should be the case! I only tried it with the 10x10 image so didn't realise how slow it was.

Comment: @Kuba I usually use Mr Wizard's [`renderImage`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21488/862) function for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Kuba Merely looking at the code I do not see an obvious reason for it to be slow.  I shall see what I can find with a closer inspection.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Deserves own question?

Comment: @Kuba I think so, whatever the explanation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If you figure it out, feel free to post both. I'm leaving soon and will be in move during weekend. Not sure if I will find time.

Comment: @Kuba Self Q&A posted: [(76610)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76610/121)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a slightly compacted re-implementation of Kuba's routine. Its only caveat is that it will not work for gradients with non-equispaced colors, like `"BrightBands"`; the routine can be modified for that case, but it will be a bit more complicated.

```
chimeraColors[cols : {__String}] := Module[{bl, cl},
              cl = ColorData[#, "BlendArgument"] & /@ cols;
              If[! MatchQ[cl, {cc__?(VectorQ[#, ColorQ] &)}], Return[$Failed]];
              bl = Transpose[Join @@@ {MapThread[Rescale[#1, {0, 1}, #2] &,
                             {Subdivide[Length[#] - 1] & /@ cl, 
                              Partition[Subdivide[Length[cl]], 2, 1]}], cl}];
              With[{c = bl}, Blend[c, #] &]]
```

Some examples:

```
cfun = chimeraColors[{"DeepSeaColors", "ThermometerColors", "SolarColors"}];
LinearGradientImage[cfun, {600, 60}]
```

[image: a chimeric gradient]

```
cfun = chimeraColors[{"Pastel", "CMYKColors"}];
Colorize[ExampleData[{"Texture", "Bubbles"}], ColorFunction -> cfun, 
         ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: weirdly colored bubbles]

---

**Added 6/30/2016**

I present here a routine for the generalization of the OP's desire to use different color gradients in different intervals. This avoids the slowness observed by Kuba and the Wizard by directly constructing a `Blend[]` function from stitched-together pieces of the component color gradients. Here it is:

```
bricolage[lst : {{_?NumericQ, _String} ..}] := Module[{cc, cl, dc, dl, gl, il, kl, nl},
          {nl, gl} = Transpose[SortBy[lst, First]];
          If[! (And @@ Thread[0 <= nl <= 1]) || 
             Complement[gl, DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`gradientSchemeNames] =!= {}, 
             Return[$Failed]];
          nl = Sort[nl]; If[Last[nl] != 1, AppendTo[nl, 1]];
          cl = ColorData[#, "BlendArgument"] & /@ gl;
          If[MemberQ[cl, l_ /; ! VectorQ[l, ColorQ]], Return[$Failed]];
          kl = (Length /@ cl) - 1; dl = Subdivide /@ kl; il = Partition[nl, 2, 1];
          dc = MapThread[Take[#1, Floor[#2 #3] + {2, 1}] &, {dl, il, kl}];
          cc = MapThread[Take[#1, Floor[#2 #3] + {2, 1}] &, {cl, il, kl}];
          cc = MapThread[Flatten[{If[#1[[1]] != #3[[1]],
                                     ColorData[#4, #3[[1]]], Nothing],
                                  #2,
                                  If[#1[[-1]] != #3[[-1]],
                                     ColorData[#4, #3[[-1]]], Nothing]}] &,
                         {dc, cc, il, gl}];
          dc = MapThread[Union[Flatten[Insert[#2, #1, 2]]] &, {dc, il}];
          With[{l = Flatten[{dc, cc}, {{2, 3}, {1}}]}, Blend[l, #] &]]
```

At the moment, the routine does not support color gradients where the colors are not equispaced (e.g. `"BrightBands"` or `"M10DefaultDensityGradient"`). Otherwise, it works quite well:

```
(* OP's color function *)
cfun = bricolage[{{0, "AlpineColors"}, {1/2, "SouthwestColors"}}];
LinearGradientImage[cfun, {600, 60}]
```

[image: half-and-half]

```
cfun = bricolage[{{0, "IslandColors"}, {2/5, "LightTerrain"}, {3/4,  "SandyTerrain"}}];
Colorize[ExampleData[{"Texture", "Bubbles"}], ColorFunction -> cfun, 
         ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: more weird bubbles]

Answer (score 3):

One approach:

```
 ImageApply[ 
    List @@ Piecewise[{
          {ColorData["AlpineColors"][2 #], 0 < # < .5},
          {ColorData["SouthwestColors"][2 # - 1 ], .5 < # < 1}
                     }] &, Image[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]]]
```

or

```
 Image[Map[ 
    List @@ Piecewise[{
       {ColorData["AlpineColors"][2 #], 0 < # < .5},
       {ColorData["SouthwestColors"][2 # - 1 ], .5 < # < 1}}] &  , 
                   RandomReal[1, {100, 100}], {2}]]
```

( *identical* timing .. )

Answer (score 2):

This is simply the correct version of your original approach:

```
Graphics[{Raster[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], 
   ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{ColorData["AlpineColors"][#], 
         0 < # < .5}, {ColorData["SouthwestColors"][#], .5 < # < 1}}] &)]}]
```

> [image: img]

`ColorFunction` is an option of `Raster`, `Image` has no such option.