# Major slowdown when using a ColorFunction with more than one named scheme

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, bugs, color, system-performance

**Bug introduced in V10.1 or earlier and persists through 11.2**

---

Earlier [Kuba noted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76449/coloring-an-image-with-two-color-schemes-based-on-a-range/76471#comment207947_76463) a major slowdown with code Simon Woods posted.  Here is a simplified example.

First a color function using two different named gradient schemes:

```
fn = ColorData[If[# < 0.5, "CoffeeTones", "DeepSeaColors"]][#] &;
```

Now its use to colorize a random array:

```
Colorize[
 RandomInteger[99, {100, 100}],
 ColorFunction -> fn
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

This is conspicuously slow for such a simple operation.  Interestingly this has *nothing* to do with `Colorize` or how it uses `fn`; it is inherent to `fn` itself:

```
fn /@ RandomReal[1, 100^2] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 4.746
> ```

What's going on?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems that there is a significant overhead every time a color scheme is switched.  Once a scheme is loaded each use is fast, but changing color schemes apparently unloads and reloads the mechanism.  The result is that the speed of application is directly related to the frequency of switching.

With sorted values there is only one switch and application is fast:

```
fn /@ Sort @ RandomReal[1, 100^2] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.014
> ```

The same is observed within `Colorize`:

```
Colorize[
  Range[100^2] ~Partition~ 100,
  ColorFunction -> fn
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

With semi-frequent switches the performance is in between:

```
fn /@ Rescale[Range[100^2] ~Mod~ 100`] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.234
> ```

One can get a sense of the magnitude of the scheme reload procedure with this:

```
ColorData["DeepSeaColors", 0.7];  (* preload DeepSeaColors *)
ColorData["CoffeeTones", 0.1];    (* preload CoffeeTones   *)

tr1 = Trace[ColorData["CoffeeTones", 0.3], TraceInternal -> True];

tr2 = Trace[ColorData["DeepSeaColors", 0.7], TraceInternal -> True];

ByteCount /@ {tr1, tr2}
```

> ```
> {519512, 10407576}
> ```

This shows that the [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) for a reload is ten megabytes in length!  And this is *after* previously using both color schemes.  So this huge procedure is called every time a different color scheme is used; no wonder it's incredibly slow!

It seems to me that this massive overhead is a bug, plain and simple.  My evidence is that using `{sceme, "Reverse"}` avoids the problem.  The use of `"Reverse"` causes the raw color data to be used in `Blend` (rather than the scheme name) [as I once discussed with J.M.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/conversation/internal-colordata-functions-j-m-mr-wizard).  Note that alternating color schemes are *still* being called *by name* -- only the `"Reverse"` parameter is added.

```
fn2 = ColorData[{If[# < 0.5, "CoffeeTones", "DeepSeaColors"], "Reverse"}][1 - #] &;
```

This function performs as we might expect the original one to:

[image]

A `Trace` shows that the massive overhead is avoided:

```
ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}, 0.7];  (*preload DeepSeaColors*)
ColorData[{"CoffeeTones", "Reverse"}, 0.1];    (*preload CoffeeTones*)

tr3 = Trace[ColorData[{"CoffeeTones", "Reverse"}, 0.3], TraceInternal -> True];

tr4 = Trace[ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}, 0.7], TraceInternal -> True];

ByteCount /@ {tr3, tr4}
```

> ```
> {898696, 897736}
> ```

This is still quite a long Trace for such an operation.  We can avoid it if we use the raw color scheme data as Kuba did in [answering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76471/121) the question that prompted this one, however for this example it can be done more simply.

The raw color data is available by using the Property `"BlendArgument"`:

```
Head /@ ColorData["CoffeeTones", "BlendArgument"]
```

> ```
> {RGBColor, RGBColor, RGBColor, RGBColor, RGBColor, RGBColor}
> ```

We can simply construct or our `Blend` from this data and use it instead:

```
mem : gradient[name_String] := mem =
  ColorData[name, "BlendArgument"] /. x_List :> (Blend[x, #] &)
```

Just replace `ColorData` with `gradient`:

```
fn3 = gradient[If[# < 0.5, "CoffeeTones", "DeepSeaColors"]][#] &;

 Colorize[RandomInteger[99, {100, 100}], ColorFunction -> fn3] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

*Prestidigitonium!*

Comment: Good work! Did you report this to WRI?

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks.  I did not.  If you feel like filling out a report go ahead.

Comment: @Sjoerd By the way do you think this should be tagged as a bug?

Comment: Hmmm... "A software bug is an error, flaw, failure, or fault in a computer program or system that causes it to produce an incorrect or unexpected result, or **to behave in unintended ways.** " (Wikipedia). Since I believe the execution time explosion to be unintended behavior I guess one could call it a bug, although the end result isn't incorrect.

Comment: I will report this as a bug referring to this page.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries did you report this? If not, I'll put in a bug report for it.

Comment: @rcollyer didn't have time for it. So, if you could do that it would be great.