# How do I color an Image generated from data such that one range of values is one color gradient and the others another color gradient

Tags: color, image

I can generate a Gray scale Image from some data that I collect. However I am trying to figure out how to generate the image with two color gradients or color scales based on the value. For example negative values are Red gradient and positive values are a blue gradient. Another example since gray scale rescales from 0 to 1 have 0 to .5 be a red gradient and .5 to 1 be a blue gradient.

If its possible creating a scale bar or a bar legend would be nice.

Comment: related Q/As:  [How can I combine two color schemes for plotting?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71697/125), and [Coloring an image with two Color schemes based on a Range](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76449/125), and [Major slowdown when using a ColorFunction with more than one named scheme](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76610/125)

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, if you're just planning on using the barebones function `Image`, you could do something like this:

```
col = Compile[{{z, _Real}}, {Sign[z]/4 + 1, Exp[1 - Max[Abs[z], 1]], 
Min[Abs[z], 1]}, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

which produces a basic red-blue color scheme in `Hue` colorspace.

Example usage:

```
Image[col@Table[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 10, 0.01}, {y, 0, 10, 0.01}], 
 ColorSpace -> Hue]
```

[image]

Note that this has no labeling, legending, or other options, so this is only useful if performance is a concern (like on large datasets).

Comment: Edit and upvote, if you dont mind

Answer (score 1):

Use `ColorFunction`.

```
Plot[Sin[500 x], {x, 0, 1}, ColorFunction ->
    Function[{x, y},
        Piecewise[
            {{RGBColor[0, 0, 1 - 2 y], 0 <= y < .5},
            {RGBColor[2 (y - .5), 0, 0], .5 <= y <= 1}}
        ]
    ]
]
```

[image]

A bit ugly, but you get the idea. Here the line of the plot is colored based on the `y` coordinate. The documentation for `ColorFunction` is quite good and has a lot of examples.